# Find a repeater that is within another repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nested-repeater

Ok so my issue is I have three repeaters. Within that repeater I have another repeater and a third one in the second. There is more in between but that's not relevant. Below the HTML is my VB code. My issue is that rptCrashPercentageAvg reutrns Nothing. How can rptCrashStatsDisplay access rptCrashPercentageAvg?

```xml
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCrashStatsDisplay" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptCrashPercentage" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="statsRowA">
                        <td class="emphasis" style="padding-left: 20px">
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CRASH_TYPE_DESC") %>:
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                            <%--background-color: <%# Iif(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CRASH_TYPE_PERCENT")>DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"COUNT(*)"), "red", "null") %>"--%>
                            <%#String.Format("{0:N1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRASH_TYPE_PERCENT"))%>
                            %
                        </td>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptCrashPercentageAvg" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                                    <%#String.Format("{0:N1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AVG_VAL"))%>
                                    %
                                </td>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

```vb
Private Sub rptCrashStatsDisplay_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCrashStatsDisplay.ItemDataBound
    Dim dv As DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
    If Not IsNothing(dv) Then
        Dim rptCrashPercentage As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("rptCrashPercentage"), Repeater)
        Dim view As DataView = dv.CreateChildView("statRel1")
        If (view.Count > 0) Then
            rptCrashPercentage.DataSource = view
            rptCrashPercentage.DataBind()
        End If
        Dim rptCrashPercentageAvg As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("rptCrashPercentageAvg"), Repeater)
        Dim viewAvg As DataView = dv.CreateChildView("statRel2")
        If (viewAvg.Count > 0) Then
            rptCrashPercentageAvg.DataSource = viewAvg
            rptCrashPercentageAvg.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try making sure you're looking for it in the correct place. It'll look in your repeater's Header for the control and since it won't find it there, it'll be Nothing the first time you try and use it.

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    Dim rptCrashPercentageAvg As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("rptCrashPercentageAvg"), Repeater)
    'Shouldn't be "nothing" here.
End If
```

Otherwise you could try a more inefficient method:

```
Dim rptCrashPercentageAvg As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("rptCrashPercentageAvg"), Repeater)
If rptCrashPercentageAvg IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim viewAvg As DataView = dv.CreateChildView("statRel2")
    If (viewAvg.Count > 0) Then
       rptCrashPercentageAvg.DataSource = viewAvg
       rptCrashPercentageAvg.DataBind()
    End If
End If
```

Edit:  Also, since it actually *is* a repeater, you shouldn't need the CType.

Comment: That does work but we actually went with a different approach. We decided to on the database side pass all the data back in one table. This way it all goes into one repeater instead of trying to have a repeater within a repeater